# Liquibase override liquibase.properties via command line

Tags: maven, liquibase

In my pom I have:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
         <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${liquibase-version}</version>
         <configuration>
             <propertyFile>${basedir}/resources/liquibase_local.properties</propertyFile>
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I want to be able to override the `propertyFile` when invoking via the command line. For example I thought this would work:

```
mvn liquibase:update -DpropertyFile=./resources/other_liquibase_local.properties
```

This however does not work and the original property file referenced in the pom is used...

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override path to property file to be used. Liquibase allows you to override the properties configured inside the properties file.
If a property is specified in both, the properties file and the command line, the command line value will override the value in the file.

You will have to change the path to properties file in you POM or you can specify the properties which differ from the one in pom over CLI.